# Wipe exif metadata

Tags: jpeg, exif

I need to remove almost all tags from images metadata. I want to keep only a fixed subset of tags.

I'm searching for a good lib that support both reading and writing of JPG.

( I prefer to use Java as it's portable, but I can also use C/C++ if needed)

Comment: Have a look at `jhead` it is  much lighter weight than ImageMagick and easier to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the ever comprehensive [ImageMagick library](http://imagemagick.org/script/api.php) that comes with interfaces in Java, C, C++, and a dozen other languages? In particular look at [mogrify](http://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) tool, which can accomplish what you want:

```
mogrify -strip image.jpg
```